# Can't open this Config.xml file which is from my router

Tags: wireless-networking, router, xml

I have a D-link DSL-2750U router and under the Management section there is a option called "Backup my settings". When you click on it it'll download a file called `config.xml`. When i try to open the file it's just random characters that doesn't mean anything. How can I open this file properly? I've tried changing the text encoding. Nothing helps. When I use the backup for my router it works just fine and sets all settings based on that file.

The request when you click on the "Backup my settings" button:

```
Method: POST
-----------------
Host: 192.168.1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:74.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/74.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 19
Origin: http://192.168.1.1
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://192.168.1.1/cgi-bin/webproc?getpage=html/index.html&var:menu=maintenance&var:page=system
Cookie: sessionid=53b72ce5; sessionid=53b72ce5; language=en_us; sys_UserName=admin
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
```

Response Headers

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-type: application/octet-stream;
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=config.xml
```

The config file

```
CONF*?蘣tGatewayDev ?  Wu余=#x滍絢s鄹?鷜织槡齸X腱?┗售U奷g|F??NM壎yL慫e秋??$?HI墥`]b涭~ 庖h4?8?/戒x廴{耒薤邵墅?縀??O~引r兵?~sZ磉N袼 &歯朘7~Ki譏靽??~綃?纒敕Si}??骄箢,yBd懔?黧哳./?2?F玉x?s鸠FS@&n?f?軺饪x?N? <緲L@U猁貪{7?祔7奮?r辕翅黸籎鉥覈Ｉ冱)??X鋊v9帰战;咢玉葁胔濜?┉?啡`綆婢涾Q*=鷠8F醔昱/付鹕?蕉啐靗|v~}u1?泘>鱟卸#Kxy耨r"}1}['?6?}??熉:9f??說y锱?g!?沺?嗈t>7鞊c/慕珛?9V瘭鮁?豉??委?聟/?~A渄lfU+嚲?厰v;]A ;?0?M屍\瓊蔖`?3-?掜
T匠枓靖彚纒CX ~嶩鄻莠???駻Db殳^^??RS$垍╀硗樺sO喚榶榽眥?~??T?碩/輕铄b  萪"砨7\疈??襝淭萯澡帴_@&k邿G銒????蟦瑅骋臄?娗鎥,?蛎?℉?R'荁阵曬"|?铭?7`$涁嬞言痔邀?>??弱?嚸?嗹櫿da F?^p?揭篖秋漀撕8?!蠱€縷-]??c鬓蕫煝シN愢`T妚e瀮V屸7?ESc出庀k/I阔5[厐蠫込鹔a鏳LK柘1榥鱜L梟?g躕z难b3O唩籢W鑈??/鲚 嬻2溒荟琭酚旃?'傶L燱7?y馴鳫?P8\ｈ!褔*J??ó繚^瀩??8爈2,?惮P?P芁    ?众皱?慜?痌媴r儕
    ?+\璱`YcNW轡
e4 钀湠屷?x嘃D娱j4?剓粋;俁推閆?\?5b}籒n邹(????MC应?蕰q羧~F脃?湡紁臱?鲀篳    偞沛蠔i陡虂?嬍?YFPd儱%騊?冬Fw恘?h?V|k7|{!m _鴜垫b蛞f時M爪?v砣柳b>-籐矻KV[怅陵K#锪?骚???DD絀u旞传蕣P8vρ&瀧梼!1狈^?[QqG}晐%=?韫7天倉:庢n€?B惒d?鸸顯?榕HB鹩d硇?L蹽窘霖蔩2浒E)M踅輔Z街這VH懖恗??谢o"s鏾芄Bz?r鈢?毰V籛祻﹥歿?????W洪銖碔{cE?N蝕揟c褩*`lfVg?崫z@歀?Q|鑖6?D馻犻E-湝
命辮up(>t1櫈
?褜x?觗沰拣J忠  ?捆(L罋锸%KC> [e餮[Xv儿W磲蒎D筨聴履:{▍禛?r-棤??銂?諛湒X?硖悯?|$諽鯻ユ療阚砡嚳?灡Us膓勠Z鑲醼Rqe;w咒胋bf   f?糢0C?e8Xo@'礠1?7?↖? 3槜.X道A慨/)0?皿8娢浉蒘賻按!垐_a所$??O搙3?俬 K嵏€=Nń逌==滩镅繙]?DY
襮  ]挢鎦$餆抎?>?螒?r,鹂~详Y钳摭q?Kl?k爄  鸙?Nm?49B勛w絶嶁卨/I蘖%0g'O臦€%g啅揿鮏蒆VA?Z鴖?崡螨B丩聫翳楈悊25黣鱽広m7-?I皎憫碡e较Cf==qc玄 _k捯曾P'
C癹?龒鳠嵎N?ж剪霑?郈曰p=A濂)符
JE潒囮??%?凳pV翆疔誧??吱捪???~}絚`漹A葖?y?鼶R?涚W?o濰耣B揔諾X?:uM沕XS┿?W妴Ju纰??nt该GaD~
僛w篘?蹝忖鋧:澼^暉8B{BF橊岘刅[d?O?2訇穂璅腼<葯?H#@鄡"?醙?| ?滁皿V? ?∠欱?#缣価P
\4*蕴鹙0侕d?釲皀鐢RySd??讴?S鴲ZPK硎E囜碩慂V‥蕀竳鏞q??XC筦袕oWp?悏lUm嘐e??/夁袅9%撫茲>涏焚q?膊??>停%梓寴鍀$?5蘖7q??wNe傥{辤态N抠?釖藺 莒?嶣?€??2??`蛗?n?X扩鱞A騝犛嬮?*s(筼?鴶L]梵?騀?H╠躧?(?R6涳-{f9D贁q?下?癢N;鋎炀yq?奯?NJ栌東塉-a2阘y??貵?O?滾║鹑挝r剅?(畄鮯H9#寖讋匔V蒑譝}匨nW?糞B+楾楩A?!迸?審?诽蒏{W#焁t軼h?歾(le晆圢c"?ゼ摬)靯堼牛价榚p芠妳栢萐濁*烙m?TX4獑剙FR?k ?E络€篅騝c?亦捧H?聣?3=Z觱kn#<?a醥&-e?5BU?鬘?覈????O"+??a?T祹綋鉘攡擳醘%懁漋x渻9r儢茦认N疬D??撘E挎?鹾?f?8v脇ㄧ.Ap焃尴衅'R'骦B?\熱?匃橘{? 荸7璣髈攒?錪蜝?!??Q增r5p湯佨I珗N燈?′峛b豰vf0歗玡钵pf`蜋?3淌AN縡8t9M??获<?撕+3e?s勪$羲<噩??y粠Y媠銜j蜡€D?蘆f簂?=毯皭奍Rb?譨?咄蹽墎讉~?鵕柃蕼?剅?～剶.氧ej賻?摂@Y笲?r洵?罃? ??帠﹌$t"鏔斒#L隶   ^蕺艑l揟鷤b-嗖V转;螗美髀映鍚z
.?汥ФJ?8澠-?驛叙]uT<Z纙
琤E虫E?峕X??}=?z@??=黎F0z€??pxz€?6对F(?F0z€??`? ??欣?沎?M?旇M?=黎F0z€?Oh鉄?鮻栄J魛栄?`? ?=黎嚙答霄杬@坭%z@坭F0z€??`魛糜邙ggK=燾魛=燾? ?=黎F0z泪?互?z@??z€??`? ?=囵魛.麵?魗q?泹U绬k葍?F+HYt詭,hJ畍d5戦=はt啍e/S=2f龟懢T?穃}豒?I枍鯆兒KZUぁu勔:Du-T旈O胵洎>d1q媒'&绕?B?襽9匰A渲?eLA矴撤?雩t翾*d恪鴄?P[]錒栣鐣8?ㄤ鎠絾t~貑t
拆闤絾l
?h菳啕z
冱a瞃袗呂嬽蝉}70篜4:}詋况徶~E别艾^鹵~傣+剠F苲碜诏H裣灤齰V恳@鞘Vh锘姻?け)蓌89頰輄????錜値??陨
v5  ?I淦X攁\v)'陇驫藔火覶?\x盽;抧s濥??⑻&嵿埴?RPZ.L麕脾瞈竎$Tげ?F%崥G渼蓇>e??Y吽緮l??凇W傕8t鯜踸庨津嵶瘤^敏^鵱颼{痠z瘄孂m{O鹤3漋动=碞3珳苀:?n;鳦?肠Qf??禐?聎n紞?F籝?嵥~3擛 挽?1aEвY吕婛Bぬ檥S#筃! `狄N??r氮Q5憢早<坁禌?(?畵婬d#暁D槼跈j襷盶+}TrNf鬸W瘷b=訫茍訉Ty??2Ｘi柧?f丙 ?貍熉?{MG螫峏臍捫\梵妜??'记€?毌屉€荘yp?嚵鬘メV soY??b?"C鬩?囅齸JYKS【賔R??xMd饥螾霆姭勔褬?2hI禵铍R瀅H旅丙?墟r*!?赭洡??!#:羓毮灮??@?訲BB戲?Q?鶉裷?壏狓鴟?
Q?鞴€吋N?l鈛2?GE灲O椐?o?糥<r8漀N帣魈 崮姩绦2%?^O櫼?,眹3V-3V獗姄?K%籇匳{Z綤rJ?j誃>i枤h虋氿櫐M  毘P& 婶`綊(
毼?*腂Y悊謑跏c5c狧箹+擩+i磛&8鹯逡*/U狶迨,X?乏{#ˉY旴晍K訔畸廃5鼄態0N看j毂(佼湧∷?'嗰np晼忍B蔓a箴嗯c/|蘓匓7'?＇;⒘o%j逦熃?]?VHF夿R躃`?gQh    VHO譪{soA9D袉戴 瓝S7gＹS飙煝@掜?玱[6?竽5?Y?wNJV?Z
侴?yZr=1殎諒~席/*Ff?竐+m??Y?JN)[l醃殨委Xn4狜H昪痐経+言氚扸G?昇Qi}lD?旻T⒉衜F[T6孷?*沥4虏@X贔X?Kh}ゥ憇r罫[?崪覹  崢+s?sF添\?zbj嫻?s赽產腬憳k1g能闻\★捕榢1Wa譲腬仒k1g能闻\》慷橂榮c??#?V?^愌杝]#鐚q?鐚?T1W塅[条寴3?c?b頟臷喘礓\fq2偽樼寉?簝t?I???胧W?崦3s鞋XU昈ァ魵壃&R蘲?+`F?7灊嫑敥H牝穢x褅絀V沝?≈齛唩栬]Aθ)寻?r??￠?笧?+7溈U◥擰?C肃Y贇叓螱?葻y???2蹑x}]?榒V髯(^皟?瘇揥hL箣?聓?*^(>綐L 稳w胔濜蟮?訹?}???q* 荑??掔1瞷螒蓊?v$B訢~躼+/襻虰筛赛??e?絟#Q"R{?
?n7q?腰Y??鄟薾?叇泣`=悗硋/諓 QN7蠊穅(Sr?I?€s?6抱
@?€翄?叟z谒兺爟#aCp梸?7霜p6鐍?'病?L凷.旍鍃?}L|0杳?'aOvFTK$嫎V@瀋€难塸袀=筤Gs淌榌镺.允pMQ錘?E犃R囥=?&HR?d尣PR遴D,豹*?eJV茼裘v% d?a瞛昑唫媍掄?堿ps蔶?Bⅰ2圵?+#n?鷨s 諳鐏?G5尡朳%w槲?nEM`=岭{崀o=魸72\?XM纅0J軀嶂予?熵X挃蟔??釛`概宿e?畷该嫝兞E轺醖昱/)y婓???輲J6B?iKg肟u鋁麳?S?9賒jＺ6:?C皠)?Xr姭b5heb藚J^?c醱€瀂 湍
`u狽?n鉨I沣&H岹燽?L??
P耡迕PWQ燲"赞R?j
)ovKY!bj裰p?襘揨怿S?浹?XX.蒗37H淰雸?閟剮4壅螥畉?8鞿GQ?苤;陱&孫引0q@!?欢f 碵G?eHU％雵侣?a騔R［祑1A?^?碊&ip嗓驼??A?q?d隣?鵯f?RSb旃??菤
$?""r??9??潬态?4W
9傝誟銭耋劋Y???崴y猦
;蛒?'?鮁撰殎"曁8'?Q#E 刻FJm?f籕rKf2ｚ朰鷳濦j
哲(q塜:粀~絖H=@?時纕桹梻?煼pf 9狝伮柝}в锏輣?涡處剘#蜆鲲爆兣ˉXO:`焤(eCDj嘦n=筆hl?拖G慯扟Yd€iY Cr:?兣RgxL(K洤鏯籍诊s媼尟紑I?鴂擥vыfA)43U造l|v~}u1?汮肱?7F绊轃徏纚勨Z诧?蜓_◆?忀?绊/T??绸芵U ?C5?9{V鬗??B]杛I*?gY掆謌[2N櫂拞佳4R镴
娢Q粂暂胆p気?,H鼖_R?櫳A-[?(nS貺K?禄'?瘿€睷袚銓岎}荠s9_F&[瞅/J廘?b憫孍嚖丯?b靈霡?2i兑敬?辔
U6Ux?!"凼凌親畺):焰:l3!U煩煠?W\)涬Jf麰瞓╖LF睩? ???K0┮JTi濺&?无訁楄?钼親侵謾? 7蹺?m℡a ※餭喪媍o1??&寗迍j瑻搎r_寿m#N鎪&貥?O?`Ws啞,K礖??J裠砄诛男凍膳?L-┼赊1??€傮Ez?.篚p膷嬙dI鋦TLo?慩妼譌b筦?祾?7佸3鹈纾y碙?g/蔈?泺槪怡e?鹋秏?缶?鶹黮代=凤诃w飓讫驾w卟籝y?鞐?笪#? 靭?O澸YⅠI磳r鏃φ僾J醍Tf腗?潢`褮璑\ω?e{v沛称1账*姄f酙晙粸渠J?斺蘙s(v?擇'＇靗?F壽S??O?E8季侦w;齠::>墸@瓪狧e??dз昂^v鑱H?€f?由q朝q縷饟?j塇BΟ钞郜锼%Xe?鵮好?5豸\92b桚茮{'q5U@哱暲嶵乎犎y?u醁r5)帲X?95P?,Gt鷖w漈l慘Xr蝲碰譻0*諸銻 V┅?WJ6ARe|JP睑趍[?挈!庈E?锁敔暒眰?h?X惈Ag詿l3曏??絬]近抉?y缁X鋙Wf?翓鴙谎m4画鞼鶹毁鑔@[韛粉弁氝??t輔5毻浆龒V逞?鄄滐Qh4歿S纋:@E€}Hc颋昼})偲q悐€夙€獉夙夙涊﨩港oたH唢f?,睇Z鋮?橙汦?騠?嫾Y?鍱>旺 ?婳?? k?€驼@緦蛩n莎涒&浗鑵xh]ｎu湞.琩ad??!$將
螦湀?OM瘻撹5骬U?捿.溮瘺猠s?乶2Z柣B?嬪.质].曽X)鞅P頲澻?汞Ur_K渚V?/惖徏卙粢H颵τ嬔說)Ho?jJ?勦籜W橐>公媝醹?恟??$F?MV?O礆 揤軅潮&<w    轖珶:,EN*萜挋"瑣i,#彙字S騐忲??砚宸`釦f賥/<
Xz[?6?肒鯑) ??饓+/?SY顠忘?徨k諂~啞垉?碯8$SJ$麗?彴K鯆+僸P1腼4穬殫牐+'窣岺w鋷
蛺?续兣?'??JP艞i壉畻~傇甸f峱痩6EmS?E-柭秬鰑烘铗?\y紦揷殧斑&討. KL誁cP犫俦€啻X)JY??
"Y蠷 楮NＹ唓炝.?薔U櫢満癯?Iha?鳪〩鈝?y&'Q?濻埚?剔V睺髠6梑瘉GI馑鴠8Q?SPJE?巃??~SV樂?M褹燹z遏丯岘9)? 藠蜦a醏g隋儖dr咖沉焘鶭*?鲞<z? 黗r睅倈=裐?&㎜歂パ拪   廡uA⒃}㏕脤I唜~3?>摰g>痀t饘w昩H圂焘R傒耳鞻鷭陘[嗿餂*??ig乡p$桮?:渇,@.X墧熛疜攖埞?盥攥? ?澮摿葞yr?{晢1拴俐G?
JbA9虖yl%5餼K啐c(?"![N浡I檾襀{?7Ｉ轁M?;慰靱gＨ'?耓=蓬??諃[??CK}毋7t?鯺岔丷穖Z镲?諉闾?w硐體饎惢溩癮蔐 ?.棹O`
[H騘娿?璩彏诗7bzpp6)睷燴5淟`?ê?ggg@O玔a9;^封Jv閷欮q鰁?CpR岢?浴qr??裻s鹊弇9?蝝??3??&?笡枂茫冷L?l餧y?p+?Z豦汀,?\猫谵貂?娒|)L籈奄羐?俸磉?i 裻磚~鞴荠s鵚*8 ?;P鍢C]Z&?栰蛹?薪ｘ
_绂嬅g枅(q0Ｒx廿Q    hL灄羷j?`|珝, pvEx?z?菸琜?髎A浻lz)倪??(N~6│7毆嶼彼覆Z派
甾y-o???冪?{)滎?5?q?勎=??鴕fLheR}fuz潕粘陂ㄠ?)d輈?劫q和?$掳SD皣倃跐?yt踮;]莕胔z2?衆?@Y?欐枍pD4?3ZT鑈n籏?烁貳7舉叹爏_鼴,閣 悅貯!7l!瞸5忾W祪裘?驰蚟踛YN坳5歮榳b鱣攵莶漬穉wZ幱i魷熭+皖6渘с?璿费贈彋c圯6鴰予u汒:屒c萯6{遁?g_圀M岸挫f费m7琋溬堘Aqz.
Q??缪圔鎡?贛蹪n?V?-嫥?╔,?侬蚧v?侬r妏同?0€佐蓫絽?のE?羋#撚9鄱&?,XGV9
2￢xRq凥k???C]Xm?mS6?鳺
%/i臨│.砷Z6op?9:jQ?aㄆI?{鉢SRy?恐W8?鷆?堥??'涀?溮V毉f$I艡?庤?淺vi幒l┏'晻.薫画嗯{q?4t溰瑻泩簲&??z!4Nx_翫教rq瀂V?嶡?]?載?)聛?9騖錧.倗8醒毝觠?橆栒奱注?垣[*?/??o@J毐?戒)Z>E磾G蓺涷?#?畂.>~]S?驸{?嗷2D錷旅€鳣(媶-K掋Mr6Aq硤??P~槖蟪怶^f斐 孍\Z鎄YH頏P
樷p'僤H?膊T杽 &??F6G弐芉x?
$?xk/箮頔y$B郟濄?s
髪I箁标%浾8郅叅y勲#?S鈑栄e渃梽M?
)?缟 o糋q酩y*V鹟
鮏ヽ煂E你杤橣畷   檁珲?+追V騩畏z搃fZ熫]^N?p堮?p?3笸?qVn覷 BY庿2手搦G庐W=?楀R津n?XZ?Q溛譽JJc>??栦G~"瀷艤\羪J嬬惟HC?麔鳠
毓x嬏8鬢O溝?Q女($碉?俛V汚窩2j準濮-欸$牝?]塊曢??黉?x豣躥抠贳骄针w{W忘９?倗<e穫蘭+xZF瘘爞СG劣锄?Lj谢飛忐僁壬徠Q?<J罶R迬OYi???T痿?x:V垮鲚y据焪麨︵?t4侴欃l祵帙Os弬?漗抗€?趥'wO喋駤J
?⒗?>垈^朚鞽淟c-?A陣P0L?1aC&X&f<?絿???浳殳9!絞笚?颻軙墴`?橒   &~B呄7?L??A
勰O8绩    &P?擿%汙  &P?旔?攑 ??邻GXk???邻[k?鋺vA7?@鴡 槾;遀?    癐簊皅
Lt傯凤6:岭
羁????鰿告n?|燒鰰??K&<?灷2?Lx瀫{O愝??JL|熰麐O 伲a擫S齑穡U?鍞H恪n<詬嚭馪7昶C]辍铧P昙画馪棿栺P7昶C輝╓h%恪n<詬嚭馪7昶C輝?u恪n<?圱~芔莞?Wu层1芔莞狵A崼zv豲\諐qU7.掀U蒴泀U7芔莞?Wu悛n\諐qUa\沼捅bk?W鯁qU7摺q&呗欆竰锴嶠 溕??9g?武茩??gr鉒n溕?筿&7武茩??gr鉒n溕?筿&7武茩?揝茩??gr╭&蠋銔3筿&7武??摏~3武茩??gr鉒n溕?筿&7武??9尥傁畼!墴s?Ei忞閞饊訩螩
6橰?澔!_?7k圔{i
鐆N??s<\%団j嬄疍5勠X渭p歺??)_裯?愡靸)简\a抋??|:鮊$w
?懠Q@?蓻銶2干棩c糷0c掃?oO编洩飧{r,a? n雋;Y_8?J?fu巐?躧 瓫?煠O</\U≯,?4y?z`樛w懔骲罍"鵅c5:V?朏丆?ddg_V~,?犒-vＱ閠趲誥?氎?R塃}h?渵{扬尔遁锒?I?o^祓睯
垐B/?嗮嗗?愑閛6杵?C模9俲S淀   Q<€ (紒此錴摾[K>?t貴佋簆P,鵣?捐{穗葮*[懥l?Fg胣5唤?1ZM皨掊膆v麧^抗€?}o雺qH#{?mIFt'演}岃?岃F莕8_W詗?裯尺l蹴^哧趸浸苒卡魋痨愭A?c剔眧镦场窂傩>勝鄑漬?螁vч磛*攮~费?踎帖=#哒蚪棈瓒祻??莶Z澂9v?莩鶣i楣}縞?緜*3树稌?{场{场i9N鱧j;紽g贳泛齰尺q寍W慎稘廻g#簑#貉韙惊橘蚞庤幷o箎w蘅o麋?lG?I?l?垌J雪纜阙?c鸂m+FS憣?(@z榾??凫l|v~}u1?泘绝x9檰Qv?I?%螟v?=M緶2e厙蜅<傴s闩o贳蠹X?｀1噼?%挢 盇減(??巂珉"侊d9确z顙?偋{FOj鈤A忿K巜祠辵F灊1)?|廏(朙'鶅摤? 
7馯? 縢屲hR鱓X樅.罻=蝹纺鴔  梼oUH
癇闗査4轓~?漴[?對汊?dR烥1狘﹚>?"r?嘎鱕薲?C潁!;煨u姭?I離П|z飺?钜
啉哚蟱毓S鹨?j┈镞漌餖鼇吷綸`蟏
∪
?r!匆偫0奮檬E8蚔&dU 鋭閙硐輅靽襄帆揷憙m?z?\?傻頢j??嵦觧Gq称M挞槙颻?蛾辝璳椗?傩'?筜骝N腈e>篭?N]媾d钎2€阹'揮?鍷9|嚂?H翛B??6gJf2囝??._翾煌嘭.荓Ko|虩曺脶?r摋?T?蕯5GT‥躚*?獷獮?'ed?娝C'<菎鳡鱼6%dz餄鱵攬e鵡韼瞢褄龜?G?f礟?昧癑`，眻袁璛5甡q棖摝J笿Y蘐I燱殍憆F涹g訹灆%鵹7!E,Nёa录 4酋?窤痤鉗Z]>@}?Hv尥欤Hlp咩麸栤?齄蜉:v咻]?带?賕墚?€+=G剬D銰∧/炕 曻衔* =?脰)v?握?裙帴凞z荿a慈mMr?4h`8V妬▄0?谐軬彟缘}l翀;"O
凁L軅e    zE(?嚦"€讳懛束??醁眳?踉o薸礼尾戯?e}糵?墱\硫』=桢鮇箘阨羏儺H姽婞祑槠徺e0壙樥屉E1u?kw鐹塰A唙桾评????翾乪??{斿撜Q栵Z)2)蛾劤??^^n
h%3W?嫷@89孕灞X㎎??簐4?D骻
]坑齑,jdb>歱遁t和^W弫$謇ㄊ:驍?j?聄p5∶MJf歴D諅?IU?腡伷蘮o傲烾 患鷺_崽Y(YX?
?s &?DV惎虐b-唋-惲 ?.7Wt?盭 =E??5Q癛?QJ&DZM毗]d?So^>UH?L烇3@籘勧X2ī麾尻?渼崺]MXk}~?B,#fjV  俛萡~?窕???fxS"#fjQ    俛萡2頁儝攼?礢鷌KX剨?]V1薄驲窗?#蒃<R阴pTゝ饯f篨銑?訩K?? 粘ゝ璕jI?p?]%???-?A}ⅧT?G昷Q湃艰撯稒y%
縇转8疍ぴ喁?Z甬"艕翋裙?,G.P? Z瞋?
TB渰慀狍崡漠 EN9p鴫継惟€衄^傂??p逯欌O?2[#嬩/?)t"3~唷?晈z猀&K櫶wY淞?佰蜮撸嶞娼Fp羇?%(?g?n娗楕餬p狰Xx醛羺?馤蚗W沞?组{:??]q羿?kNI虖?鄵|洲咮￣?睫俀?    1襇?姆WWg3婙wx塸€坕?嵁O幱?5桃癥x譃禷繾?e";z)v薊?濚Y骍4娐Gx稳?/?w$:h髋:89蜪S蕙n躟醙禃;#僙鐢)?斸厖!?#??y(?鎮T摶X:??b^HL癞钾徳g邑9'??箞5a紡??1叹犆Mh)?;苈亼?E淏釜蘙賽:9v?Z'嬝襏]???s簲?JV伶qAI?狙?誒鍻Z?)慫姞橃W??\dL爦<D1/鯅 0┝匧悂R.?涇?Ц??饚?癅=??z1鍰6聆?D鏊dl,怿zX掑#婡D!Tn茄+zs龕7(#{立牋.粟^,霊+蟍€q2听ˉy^?∝?:楥YSAe?Py﨏 ?篮==致渗??椃;(6f`xP坮PA
 )饀纔∥芪櫜飢瓗?1聾敪%r奛挊c摖`宋嫛"2kq+"3儕廱/馘皠泚
鏱3O阞f?(紮Hn煍鉫溰?隻W蚷I瘑r骏蘎?剩隼购?C.煒/莵3x璁?W捤佯m??7苏,毟忷3?IV阕鬃?sd臛0?儢n耸鯺?o農囌軁Of:黶獹?働暷?3_?糝梛壸/?ゐ\rD耳趷)[~袖??Df瞜箁D憠1唹;L[B(s獶VI= ?冄嶬梱X禹Dl册?wE_K茺s怇?侅旽5YZy?Td#.<鱩痮5N抠牖\??6?軓絎7?5?頞?黃mWN(凒4\M繴|υ    ??瞳挛.5TB蛽
2I5忤僳 ^晐0!揂(飩盒]蹮鵯陓 ix髨?U悝m1)岟m时袑?詥?R飪??诙?UI??幗yTJ?稬
d)?扥^冢?緑[拰犯尒? 照{鹂|S囑2疦榌C^?(,层???瀩佔愜 rヲ3幗餛?Z,?Q髹玾i蝃\?y侘桄w豇Hp珛a{1銶飠U?懣RoV+LP餰?'睐y矱?蟁躍)ǜ犣齰:Cy眧%岛]5抝@綽h(O$`jJ,#a謷buy穉埬@c鮵傸?鲡铼6a$勔轇w橄K[塙妴t{)?鍄uG牸$媁m傸? 木箻剰牿燺SL?f?飷!
s.d?z?%緶G?'￠峿?萝d楊
l孕呍茯秴雧蜶P怹漧8聈vR^e.\n8L??M%!惄?Z薁D珣?鏡侠L黀鮝课#YH悢;嚳J<<祹?釚7%爔3艠囎?冝襨鲔}谎靠?t?W綃雞歼G.[s?g枺弋c蒄a困︼谖慶貵庉庥*2Pyi
x滘Pv0?±?Ob帷?ヾ? E?>馡~鉩?-!ｄ恡厂8?>瘢'fI_??^棖LN礱H)a:綐^\?悵攫G{4mq虎詒"貲踯轸Z?氄懒?:K?
 €驐?[<鷄槰省朾梢耀€d琣珼qT0Q?訚蓶D鳿>萑V"挢獉?,J^闻"餽Mk&鯻鎆"R*D姵〒y昣匵FE[琕憞巎s_ m+?尲X?檒蟆sF?柊b唊<湝蜔"T停卲hV)L趹撶詟嶟荊韙€杀?C1︿Ft€(H剤Z?棾郓?RF粰喲KiX緵緸凒n8?o%^?e僚呫?骫b9璇WQ??,Q甹x?鈛?婌9皖蕚!@3澫&?3絟?rV??|r肎??S隥s*鬱懊Z~p7q?m董詩$T謴?旦)皻c:j5]i{q]纇琚籿??k6?B墚aW舐?z疧铥n?倭歊婕i蜨f?射偻王蚲|?a-^廝霼?   靬涷  崛嬍v??甐+n腍衕卂.?焼}?^礵?鲤 弬瞜H+梐HE掣摶榺F呹忈/   灶1(寍?驤m7?俫+4?折?jJ 滕!CB踅u撴!?熋??扆4`$厏?w1s眏壨F鎎/醚(R+???E 挷P焱:焔w幷退Si敥鮹峃籫翟??No0辗.r勔⒋>JY屸kn肸}沾鞦磺L彤b    鮞rZ秂窌??邽ㄓ?,?簀鋅萙? &甌 ▼衚驏韙Z
^Q鹙[{漗硩?)€? 綒w:豁4l湬9}s齅[EG|猍j灔螉?dlB绒实嶔霤~慍挮貲?槬>z??[4?.:巻.???賓 鍁?9PX嶴髄5?;Kd?;囜傶栞?祫哂''?:  :勉I鈲"KB裰W諳鮱骿?{pㄔ?s繩:蠉９ㄒ姭I箮N烺嗺麓?j要??挾??7?y?畛?遇d@€
??馉?(锳6嬃??伴鰴G?饛At?y隌z?堶"9?倍?k=b涟?蒮TA?鬫
?{飻襥覡?'e?3E?m扇??啍Q?,迈祺?处+a蒕P鉠昄籡Q-囷)?羹?凄]B鍂んＢT?h燨瘐?鹗霺'?)_牷y?9嵟6偠 惐゛薊伳q???j??倈垔畀?玳薓U谳道!橎v-"<|嫨妼?韚?<L剾?8YYu聠耍咰I<粶n??寖?岰>葓i?熈嘙糔T嘺埀&烕\^殜纩3?蕽迆窤?M8?[o0n!6?蛌屋?mL駒圶殞逛^m瀵|淓??<|?mk6筃撓j?9o崳hu镂烥钧F嚯鎟?芜｀?D偍oVン钉?XES罐&a鏴\y}豣弛;OaT摯Z籎堇呇畜?莺N?Q鞀/?mV侘EL擡恶賙?O.?Q@O涽姓~C??<課姟?9?v'侦? gN<゜劎都馏お?岵>馻{?びQ猯~Y黮撆帴殊W?Wr9蚌毇碀?W漨窚MVg稭埠鞬5申t芖OV珈1Y漖惉??琪传宻?f静璕?-柹;w?渨.迢??姑;?V?壺A$覈Y惶颇疬2o樀护a?餘晞a澾g蹌a涥g粚aL投?普l矛=??㎞F']扖UK埭茞獩瞝藇澃l7墒v敤lW示兡d&)X`种    ??Lh?虅agT携?屨>'S/???圃h薉`-洴斩I滥趍楛嬚6L?摲ヴSL?3訡唊2お齟鋯I齟G
羇R???o`≮虽2滠_=梞?丈uu眙茂昧蚳隩`謅d肬趠n0wg?喹髣5v?谝~鳷a鯫?寵?`?;踕
ca鰸5l
W? jS?~ (備8?黾|鋯B汤|闩遒E錹僉蕏0?x屗au烂b\绽竍1LV7}<撜蚫u3Y輮!MV穞?FY轀絜u揋e☉窄J窡0脍庴謢?n&}汭遞曳欞m?T?y(e摼M?}洡M?屵Amc廤?儃?趋??頶?椎刐?'転s马'扣斡箎炤X0暶~捄?佦?k麨2鋓q壬??弯N鹖s漷i&A歗?蒽d椬?Τ罬鹏d9浬LV癚贏V?菎菬!'v
?'賛8Gg瘺?-檝壁閩匿c_/镓姿8鲺r峿?c_'韶咨1鰑拫?~拪?ж緬夗'嬝>拠櫆a?L?虽39肔?墵49?璆?.=暽v€漛r喩L?黉Н???3i驹献O篚M襸?R[$i薰瘻-?_![丞I??9X吸s&C砄乎?9橎5拑u09?酊瞴7護?岕?G瘹爏%(糁I~鱱杞OⅦ嗲籏7|??遖CIK吱e翞JU光律ZR;{気s鰸=铂?{Z穋h??捎??O?_=y毜卿iVA虼鼥K!Dz萱]蛹鎛磲歿馰k胼巂?[o?繇F许wzf/こ俌[o啲靻瑵l嚞濎囙?6恑qr;B拒襤
cJ渄?吱饄'溣h?<?+G? 绹A遥Z?胀?%h廔癥+,⒓#G蜙?
ジ蘊6?蕑厠j0)沦趷@綦? x頿钋?崼?H H!轞挸e恈?⑷協3┼摗籸稞繭驆縭扢?堚%孷?霬榩 ?r佥,夊W 连帆F? i=宴觃媎釽??(6u?0M?眥n!}p峯o匹渋T,汇貼肴稖#揊鴭γ??厕??Rc9B昦o DG偫3鈗瞽搒?鸫漍X剄s}I*'GJ唃??婂L忓宐└駯砗Of蒙跏o?l罈朐@鋊仩鋃{晲r,K煉=?R绾呈稄A_%G媆?造:軝Z?餻s?斣$u恠M2s诩罗?泃殄?鎈}逶?Q??醼?糚t 貒Xv悸伩+濰鞍
|荕r$伆%.K?PAU撢騅
J??鞨g`N粙???dH/咙楜_郴簒??Yf覭讅躻-?a唦?F?X渳即???xy\7沱U @$锱撳J(鑇?A\闁移?镽4M泽仧-荧松郠瑭碮聩54v渹a徻~2?h鷯繈姶h?愯刑??礉慰妀壁??竖 拚岧 ? ??旘?変燀F!娻?馠啟^%@??髶瘷L?賫~=f??廨PI?
类漺??'罚ML媙M0x鳒b&`厂豙?EA?龋鹾-闫2轠织臠蓝?蛵囝?^垞騶諕蓀#<ZF?k
e$e隖ГP鹪['<鬒??;蕄^

:\.Y簆刌悹檶鋮g頵秙眎qn;(?阎upl瀺例柜6赑6脾y簜濫>?l#@)3A琕Ept祀B?丨PU?囑婶'?旵?0柸圗?5躚
P爍j鄪\e婮XS俄?&aK%A8姡葯(E镕ZZ?髎嶳昒玃_Vgf/   裟同G*Ol殧g/汇?c?$W?   牽?/P??葒Dz啎亗湏乹P?ド巑桲?I糆伀1CCv烕\繠^гe莑蛮邳蒣l/?S溄w:c杶?h<箃鉭錪!尊zZ葦晶?娵 ?V-3V獗奭L9S'Z?r?齑D  u俸?亷`鵸
;?樝"抒僑4"棨W椟屷=襟'欩齑I
?嚏烥駵e[偄?溎捃[xyrA??s*歸8窺宭驓L?Z
侴hA~獠跐巉`飛'w揠莜蓍峯验畏媵?夢
锓牯鲎顃鏪tz阚u:?|?o~鞱房E?縘?裣?u糊?齕魕脎鮵l?蕔撖v}奁?;{閟?鍈拷蘖?粐噪Fy遱裣?u篞搠荛皆8cR?韢咂+眦?錴???鮳;瞪冫1蕶^?H
轓

??溄_隉@鐥.:vGw3T徚jx钗@?龋S?虊?隕睅彆qD%牔?~Q9?宨C1ㄙ9墱藅V?A藋 馆B'.循肒 噣5畬g!@?釐见?xQｍ8V顪醺R??蟟_+璧^%y^
Pu}O
撞?1煌?困?.4+閈冢?(?銱蔧za
椆桬0$?t8_?1t窄岶3c笅清牦
f湲
*B絓?鞙儘莅6艣~舄~S??y
定藶A緉C⒛W?nx吠G??嫮v锞~
96?织"艣?蚖q}8?\o告谛_z鮧萷搚脡o1Uhvy钋瞢礎y€T*唹?H狕謼?啚喫占6*脥岅?艣?ヌ?G?@辕?駃碑遌4s:烀-}葈>P桦wx纝栎6?hif猸{F丆苀R_禒櫽炥F?d?靗jC? ?誳M?旼蒵Q_Q?钍E譏k#r杠b櫢?壛件d託y黪k栿?S?痣+?/<l<x邢饚t?(寥-w獷薳'鯒?服?貅o*cV鯀艣痶?冡N胃綄陭f?漥黪7@o?笄峞悉騠嫀e儆溤?艣v弃惫Y訽z9~規a}D?磴跛6?藶禷'衙C齰d蠋??H敦?殇{豱q@翕??x?洘┛X雔f礲C曫k刯3裰?賩冂Q? *_i驫蔍儶棵謜?瑑黚I偻悑4琿?G\;撠kG鰬{k吼?uO0^?澺脴5#&?x8錷*(v桊+?K?疱(Z+O聵?GfVpd镩2d栙閇8將g逽漂?26xBSb舸?劑 d綷?`廰?f蜹癄$f?喴o:w逖G侤?7蝐黢1P粿摮?fn㎏枒? ??吿4 刬Wf??J织漭訩@滬艜擯蔪n
鶬A)纮4ahJ?虩1E)怈+嚉瑹础2Z9詍瑯?▽枃Z{?4phB”u   鹄洭CA岮#陓]1＂澪壵`?漀U变?R  ?楅即?贡3j?#咱裠x}u跎
6r
s3L砤1騊0譴p簚#%困魛w|qy1S?GA蔖襣?迮鋌?淤K”?錥溫?M}19G*lA?鈾z??轙駚孝H余钝谋&@嚵€3?}Vご4蔧)J#C?Q缞?U綻Rf剕鐔午:?躀 )忸蒓糾奝啵阭竣€陛WH鶥絖蓛?諝u憮滘??絲?M?啢W5闝貗汋嬳1匽璤?X   JDぐ5?R?<VJ厅eF[#茓?僑47<k? V犷?#郁犡梣ΠCw?.H萂Ed朧P炿毀NA纼舶蜉w?挙 繭櫶G62糚?姻?P辦蚨袒粭E礧鋔=9?棵
綪(KM??P2r儠腫酫︸]??}j?偙俖愉`埳0€A犼D髨7?諝留談0o嘮t燰<嘉gxj杄1?}*蛐桍糒硙ot瓱?~?軦r皙rW梫荖z?;鉨x┻bB蚏?俫z冧畺逪阻
唤Y卄癎纍v徲 ?~撧譟;;Y;?麜V吵裾賹霅鵐z昜诮]tD9?亠鼧壂y淈&絜蚮k齺`癈?C?涬?鵐zZg
i靌?槦矺甂轰7?e≌厣矌`~?欆\\臀n?楗[M??豞遼脧ru魩渇魅n8;佝疺+k? [j皪    噻檦?pH絘L ?`L ?饈H+c8谤aL 6C??荒? ㎏*? 覡3? ?.騜砠?^)娫鸊砼`??珺/嗂粅释炦糤1A芮j闹?5-60癝∩f謮2揇諁叠??姄葚Qj歲4L曶?Qw(
)5?&壥胼v嚶,p 齉?T絈j挩极&噈店?f晇I㏎⑵晰'??ウ-G?Qyg桔類??敠敋枩%Z;1诘觝W臚T莰=簹V礕园r麯襃m侏kZ影G园r麯]⒍l?璭?UD髿f師⊿远频,芨躉nN?濜?b螛h掉=?倃癃Z18岢贪T??&笨N叵掁O*紤$箣D?mL5(咧W??譢?l???7/?L餣跒Y镯鲞%牪r>掙係Zh洗养都蛭徑繹薈O|0?+僾?0筙GA坊6?
?=悊裷x墽X'gX詬肨廱艐淆衉?昤?p?foo???;愶咱烧勲?県鴝袧8競謄蓏U
氣J誕4L誧?0O姓? ?
龚(;旷?C呿?P恀)\7g磐蔰%?U?溧疴囓t勹v|6?曊褌`铩淠?=ù,b?闼醿7qi蘘槷}d 厤瀋
瓰?唪池]鳳旃蜊犊-i????)s猏衞jh,? ??KZU
嗣
峆溞?峀徏~x(肱擫劲?d   ぺx蜅~9~栟F* Z]#嚭鶱?撼S茓?? S H蛫蕏s   \＂J@???3^n?媂[€!縜嘵?蘭?5鐼^?P0Od峂噈惤>坢纻俤嵟/r拏茬赂?8??宁釷夾s?R?&P鳛?そ榮f猦EQ,aオW;I? _轴b
辋V労?G鑮殌?谚狿w徕?j? 匇軆×綉?喲:耒掟y'訹隄焿WQcSrD蘁~ωv邶七(?C垾吙鬇栅L描Q(&碌t鰿蜔錓m [徽j碻y]P]?驩?    浾o?偮 强G玜?逭k7艻.)聇禴E嶷冋??=€? 譛:繰安?峔磐 #?.?%tZ?眦BNV*鲼(洑L塿?槽]€X ㈡T0兄`#蜝???曑h蜫g?敖x骜?麒觀\yX.2?鎶78嬨(^?i淛绕R鍦犖醶?壏(c鏗睂?剒#
(a┓x?涿f-?鴷(鹥s   洷ζп猈Q?:洚u?[y饲*??&換伭K照娔Pe?q@鐢??睷I8SAgCQ檼"k,酙G谐莭廓岇$亙%%K櫬
愇?芒??ee?/G扭€ O锘Oe5A$堷6|Ｗ饅吤?r贝B敲铄?-?酑?梙H唨?S壁挍程I囁爵 輁?婊?DR?E
蹽^樳?班sL??摿b{k?;_汩0?H??挸9д:]}i?AU8Q寺灺)>E脟i2譑e?o撷癍鶰of鲍惶沈`驱?M??恥^咋g筬o",W庖跻.揺幃,僓馛:~=╉冏碟v?%耚W迼l>8巭??輞"`?q粬杩郺:h晵"燮  洘磢l生J岮?7鬦?P敖ｘ疟瘓+?緯綇＞?#諮媸伀 兌1鎼砪匒?眍?#?`4O呗鵖咡H&鐑4楴A[奓)陟蚣5??nu髄騕.儖1€損Qxg醔?*騦9b砎
y.
痎
秚O&€+鍈翋?`瞭惴懿Y
抯`Y?P忏h騣8踯x?G:w鵑0;?? ?l聟@荗iBE?漱鼎RN敫褄讌€?鳲點[x氐哔稹僟?酂za?惏複g[荕褑8馃&??褥 ?d伆 盭愋倈酂潆dy氥秅\\柋奄v<駧k鋆Jy伕*吵褓张p瘙l鷜xq^?犘鶉鯢夆缜8诂*y抎\'? 6粄山??M??? ?厃$s?顄瀹庄Q夹喅滷?/轝O???6W茀's卭薶S暧%A鈞?魆崜#   u瓋(    [V;昚^Rd? 彸x%?k???? ;鳻6=Q?B??ギ鑬"?蟍€eb?x岁仱4艝蝪 嘪??[纥p0O K礝:9?   Lザ%磵躁I烇?%闼[x骪蘼櫎萚砆-锑璺0卻?]?祫?}剜姒7蠚€靏曹 hD齁?) {,t(-疧巗&"臬c銵蝔夵离礌?虡N禗O咧壏?3魚缫[属=?gi湝R栺<鍪蟨sfH?#?缩森琤囫8r?%F鄋s摡穯9g詔fJ旋n辏立燬#H啱肬C籂P;.*寠嫃棑I}醈鎡|?=?~鼬谜?a:*[阕r茣?:?lw7廜埠e_A尹珙:{頚钤???瀎??
??吿?h窦/.羔蠢T黃嘌.XFK@?扔吋苾牑u@rU燵?G嘢 M?檏T?瓣 U臡j捾p寘廬0?1p?祎吃g?4禨)堚L丒"[??l?庘鹠縆rbU邑DY譐舿&榶?>+??g飠骟O   'G幷cx-O虑舗qR莈赻YRm牃烯i澂w閟A#倣%[鲣Yu很4仐3俈c;玚e`掌風L(`慁屖??U*把鴍 ?送溠缊矼zuKFい??,蜘浒??茷琇  JFy?r飼覾N?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RouterPassView v1.90 - Recover lost password from router backup file:
[image: Recover lost password from router backup file]

Comment: From the information reported by RouterPassView, the `config.xml` produced by a DSL-2750U is of type `zlib/deflate` that starts at position 32. So it is possible to decode this by removing the first 32 bytes (`dd skip=32 if=config.xml of=config.dat iflag=skip_bytes`) and then decompressing the resulting `config.dat` using the method from [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/49066).

Answer (score 1):

> Can't open this Config.xml

It seems the data being returned is not valid XML, despite the `.xml` filename extension in the `Content-Disposition` header in the response.

It is noteworthy that the `Content-Type` header on the response is `application/octet-stream` and not the expected `text/xml` or `application/xml`.

So it is probably a binary data format that is not public.

The fact that there are some English words and abbreviations visible at the start suggest that this probably isn't just an encoding issue.

---

> is no way to read what is in this file?

Without any documentation of the file format it will be very difficult to make sense of the file.

One technique would be to

- download the file as Config.xml
- rename it Config_0.dat
- make one small change to the router configuration
- download the file as Config.xml
- rename it Config_1.dat
- perform a binary comparison and see which part changed

On MS-Windows you can do a binary comparison using `fc /b Config_0.dat Config_1.dat`, it will show the offset and byte values that differ.

On Linux you can do the same thing using `cmp Config_0.dat Config_1.dat`

You should be able to relate the old and new values to the change you made.

Then you repeat the process sytematically. You should gradually build up a picture of the format used and it may become much easier as the process continues.

Using a printed hex-dump of interesting parts of the file  ought to be helpful.

Obviously this is pretty tedious and is, I guess, why reverse engineering is an art that requires experience, skill and time.

Comment: so there is no way to read what is in this file? if you want to check by yourself i can send you a copy of the file

Comment: @Sarkar: see addendum to answer. You are in a better position to work this out than I am.

Comment: well it is working with that method so thank you, Marked as Correct answer